# Find a user's sponsor going infinite levels up PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, parent, referrals

Say I have a MySQL table like below.  Going from the bottom, I want to find a sponsor that has a "Status = 1". But I want to do it in a order. For e.g. I am "Mike". My sponsor is "Richard". I want to check if "Richard" has a status of 1. He doesn't. So now I am going to check "Richard"'s sponsor to see if he has a status of 1. He doesn't either.  So I keep going up, checking my sponsor's sponsor's sponsor...etc.

Normally I can do that with a single or multiple queries if I want to check several levels up. But the problem arises if I want to check infinite levels up until it finds the sponsor who's status is 1?  How that work? What would a php query/function look like checking infinite levels up?

```html
    Sponsors     Referrals      Status
    --------------------------------------
    Zack         Joey             1
    Joey         Tracy            0
    Tracy        Helen            0
    Helen        Richard          0
    Richard      Mike             0
```

Comment: A better way would be to store the first parent sponsors id with any subsequent children.

Comment: Can you give me an example? It would help me visualize.

Comment: Zack is created -> Zack refers Joey -> Joey now has a link to Zack, call it `parent_id`, now Joey refers Tracy and as Joey has a `parent_id` set Tracys `parent_id` to Joeys... So essentially anyone in the chain from Zack has the same `parent_id`. This way you can reference the `parent_id` with no sub selects etc

Comment: don't you have any primary key ? if you do you can sort desc on id and add where on status

Comment: if my understanding make sense to you, I can provide you a solution

Comment: @MoeenBasra have a shot, its low hanging.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone - I understand where you are going with it but unfortunately that's not the solution either. Remember, Zach may have a status 1 this time around, but next time he might be 0 or Joey might have status 1.

Comment: You cant have 1 or 0 is a parent or not a parent if your chaining you need a reference.

Comment: Its called a one-to-many relationship, its nothing new https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the solution definitely seems to be to have the `parent_id` as Lawrence suggests, I though I'd give the PHP solution to this assuming you had the list of people in an array already (i.e., not one query per pair, as that'd be really wasteful).

What you need to do is recursively iterate through the array, going from sponsor to sponsor until you hit a sponsor with status 1. Take a look at this function:

```
<?php
$people = [
    [
        "sponsor" => "Zack",
        "referal" => "Joey",
        "status" => 1,
    ],
    [
        "sponsor" => "Joey",
        "referal" => "Tracy",
        "status" => 0,
    ],
    [
        "sponsor" => "Tracy",
        "referal" => "Helen",
        "status" => 0,
    ],
    [
        "sponsor" => "Helen",
        "referal" => "Richard",
        "status" => 0,
    ],
    [
        "sponsor" => "Felipe",
        "referal" => "Juan",
        "status" => 0,
    ],
    [
        "sponsor" => "Richard",
        "referal" => "Mike",
        "status" => 0,
    ],
];
static $i = 0;
function getParentSponsor($referal, $people) {
    foreach ($people as $pair) {
        if ($pair["referal"] === $referal) {
            if ($pair["status"] === 1) { // we found our parent sponsor
                return $pair["sponsor"];
            }
            else {
                return getParentSponsor($pair["sponsor"], $people); // we need to go to the next element
            }
            return $pair["sponsor"];
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
echo getParentSponsor("Mike", array_reverse($people)).PHP_EOL; // Zack
echo getParentSponsor("Richard", array_reverse($people)).PHP_EOL; // Zack
echo getParentSponsor("Joey", array_reverse($people)).PHP_EOL; // Zack
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0dkOJ)

Comment: Oh wow. This might be exactly what I was looking for. I'll do some test with my real code and see how it works.

Comment: That's great! However, if at all possible, I strongly recommend you follow Lawrence Cherone's approach.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want all the sponsors having status 1 in reverse order

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
where status = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Give this a try.

Comment: No, the OP wants to get Zack from Richard, Mike or Tracy.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. It has to follow a linear pattern of going from sponsor to sponsor and finding if their status is 1. Also keep in mind, each sponsor's status could change to 1 or 0 at any time, so it may not be the same sponsor every single time.

Comment: @themaster that's why you cant have a single `status` to see if there a sponsor of many. You need another column which references the initial parent or forget about status being binary and use a reference id to the primary key of the parent. If it's 0 then its has no parent.

Comment: hmm it seems like i totally misunderstood and posted a childish answer.

Comment: if you need to avoid too many queries you can do it in chunks and then perform php check with foreach or array map

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in php is the wrong approach in my opinion as it will lead to N requests from the application to the database (where N is the levels on has to process until the sponsor with the desired status is found). One might get to optimize this but the basic problem will always be the same.

The data basically represents a tree structure (or list if a sponsor can always only refer one person).

There are patterns for representing trees in a relational DB but it will require changes to the db structure ([Nested set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) is but one example for this). [Bill Karwin has a nice slidedeck on the topic](https://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

If you are not limited to MySQL or can wait until MySQL 8.0 is released, using [CTE/Recursive queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) would also be an option.

The good part in any case is that you are not limited to just one use case once you have the tree structure in place.

*Appendum*

php isn't my programming language of choice so I cannot recommend one library in particular. But there seem to be a couple of libraries to choose from:

- https://github.com/ben-nsng/nestedset-php
- https://github.com/riquito/Baobab